# jquery selected options from one to another

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In the following multiple select box when clicked on change button i  want to populate all the selected items in `id="p_prod`" to display in `id="s_prod"` and remove them in p_prod and on click of revert i want them to be removed from s_prod and repopulate them in p_prod in the same order as earlier it was ..how to do this

```
<select size="10"  multiple="multiple" id="p_prod">
 <option value="1">prod1</option>                                   
 <option value="2">prod2</option>
 <option value="3">prod3</option>
 <option value="4">prod4</option>
 </select>

 <select mulitple="multiple" id="s_prod">
 </select>
<input type="button" id="change" value="change" onclick="val();"/>
<input type="button" id="revert" value="revert" onclick="val();"/>

function val()
{
  $('#p_prod option:selected').removeAttr('selected');
}
```

Comment: And have you tried anything? Search for 'jquery append' or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the `selcted` options using `option:selected` and append to other `select` using [appendTo()](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/). It will remove the options from first select automatically.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EMauV/1/)**

```
$('#p_prod option:selected').appendTo('#s_prod');
```

To revert you need to store indexes, and you would need some thing like this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EMauV/3/)**

```
$('#change').click(function () {
    $('#p_prod option:selected').each(function () {
        $(this).data('prevIndex', $(this).index());
        $(this).appendTo('#s_prod');
    });
});

$('#revert').click(function () {    
    debugger
    $('#s_prod option').each(function () {        
        currentOptIndex =  $(this).data('prevIndex');
        if(currentOptIndex > 0)
           $('#p_prod option').eq(currentOptIndex).after(this);              
        else
            $('#p_prod').prepend(this);              
    });
});
```

Comment: Also i need to remove the same from p_prod and how to revert back to p_prod which are selected in s_prod

Comment: I have, is it okay now?

Comment: Just do the reverse: `$('#s_prod option:selected').appendTo('#p_prod');`

Comment: if i select all the values and revert it is appearing in reverse order

Comment: Let me know the answer if u find it..Thanks